# Order by date issue

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I have a table with two columns :

```
datecreated 
datemodified
```

I have written the following query to get records in past 7 days from today :

```
Select * from mytable
Where  ((datecreated < GETDATE() - 7) or 
(datemodified <> null or datemodified < GETDATE() - 7))
Order By datemodified, datecreated asc
```

Is there any way to order by different columns e.g. if we have two datemodified :

```
1. 29/02/2012
2. 01/03/2012
```

and datecreated is :

```
1. 27/02/2012 
2. 28/02/2012
```

the select would return datemodified old to recent date and date created old to recent:

```
1. 29/02/2012
2. 01/03/2012
1. 27/02/2012 
2. 28/02/2012
```

Comment: You could use a union with two different selects, however, the example you have given would not work if a record has been both created and modified within the last 7 days.  Are you saying you want each record shown twice(once with its modified date, and once with its created date)

Comment: @jzworkman no those are separate records

Comment: Your current select statement will not work like you want. First, it is giving you rows where the datecreated is BEFORE 7 days ago, which is the opposite of those within the past 7 days. Second, it will give you all records that have any datemodified value at all--should be an AND instead of OR in the second part of your where.

Comment: Are you saying that you want all rows that have a datemodified value to be sorted first, by that value, and then all other rows that DON'T have a datemodified to be sorted on their datecreated value?

Comment: @patmortech yes that is correct I want all records before 7 days ago.. as for your second question yes that would work

Comment: 'Before 7 days ago' means any date before Feb 24 (eg Jan 15). 'in past 7 days from today' means any date after Feb 24 (eg Feb 29). Which is it you want? In your examples it seems to be the latter (since all the dates are AFTER Feb 24th).

Comment: it is 'Before 7 days ago' those dates were just an example of how the order should be :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use <> with NULL, not all SQL versions support that, use IS NULL instead. There are a few different ways to accomplish this. In your case you probably want a UNION or a UNION ALL if you want to preserve duplicate values.

```
SELECT     datecreated, datemodified
FROM         (SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT datecreated, datemodified
                       FROM          mytable
                       WHERE      (datecreated > GETDATE() - 7)
                       ORDER BY datecreated)
UNION ALL
SELECT     datecreated, datemodified
FROM         (SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT datecreated, datemodified
                       FROM          mytable
                       WHERE      (datemodified IS NULL) OR
                                              (datemodified > GETDATE() - 7)
                       ORDER BY datemodified)
```

Comment: this would not work, as if i put desc in the order it will return datemodifed desc and datecreated desc too like this:
1. 29/02/2012
2. 01/03/2012
2. 28/02/2012
1. 27/02/2012

Comment: Modified answer. Is this more what you're after?

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you are looking for -- it first orders by the datemodified, if there is one, and sticks all the ones without a datemodified at the end and orders them by the datecreated.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (datecreated < getdate() - 7)
   OR (datemodified IS NOT NULL AND datemodified < getdate() - 7)
ORDER BY coalesce(datemodified, '1/1/9999', datecreated)
```

**Edit**

I think I misread the result set you want. If you want only one date returned, that is either datemodified or datecreated, then you change the select to be the following:

```
SELECT coalesce(datemodified, datecreated)
FROM ....
```